# Easy and effective way to clean a very dirty plastic broom

Tags: cleaning, laminate-floor, garbage-disposal, dust

What is the easiest way to clean a plastic broom (I mean such as the one in the photo) that has collected a **lot** of floor dust etc?

[image]

Just hitting it against a wall to throw out all left overs is not good enough as it is too dirty

Comment: Last summer I used the pressure washer on mine.  It looked brand new after.

Comment: sweep something very rough, like a pine tree trunk or a very rough rock .... corner of a stair step or a street curb would also work .... when most of the dirt has been shaken out, dip the broom in hot soapy water and repeat the sweeping

Comment: @jsotola:If I dip the broom in water how long before I can use it again? Seems it will take a while for the broom to dry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vacuum it.

You could also comb it, with a hard metal rake. Since you didn't tell us what it is dirty with, this is my best (fits most cases) answer.

Comment: Lots and lots of thick floor dust like when you get from places that haven't been mopped for a long time. I don't know if dust is the correct word. I hope what I mean is clear

Comment: While it is safe to say "we all do it" hitting it against a "tree" or wall is going to damage it, and you dont want to pound it in deeper. Water will usually make it messier. Go with the vacuum/rake

Answer (score 0):

Garden hose, or a sink with a sprayer.

You know you're supposed to rap the bristles on the floor at the end of each sweeping motion, right? (not just tapping the armature on something at the end) Otherwise it makes a mess each time you put it back down. It shouldn't ever be all that dirty if you do that.

Comment: `rap the bristles on the floor at the end of each sweeping motion` what do you mean? Hit the broom vertically?